# Ionic 6 Capacitor React app shows white screen of death only on Samsung S21 devices

Tags: android, ionic-framework, capacitor

We built an Ionic 6 Capacitor React app (uses Firestore for db, Glassfy for managing subscriptions). The app works fine on iOS devices and 3 of my Android devices (a Samsung A53, a Google Pixel 6a, and a Samsung S7+ tablet). But it keeps showing a white screen of death with a spinning wheel on Samsung S21 devices (it has been reported on at least 3 of our customer's phones).

I can't for the world figure out what could be wrong. Has anybody had any issues like this or has an idea what maybe happening?

Not a whole lot really. I don't have a Samsung S21 device myself so haven't done any device specific debugging. But any ideas are appreciated. Ty so much for reading!